# Update Dataset inside Fragment/Activity or directly in the adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, listadapter

I noticed two patterns for handling a List Adapter's `notifyDatasetChanged()`. I was wondering what differentiates the two and if one is better than the other.

**First**

Holding a local variable inside the Activity/Fragment for the dataset.

```
private List<Movie> movieList;
private SwipeListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new SwipeListAdapter(this, movieList);
```

And then when the local variable changes, call this in the Activity/Fragment:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Second**

Passing an empty `DatasetSet` array to the adapter in the Fragment/Activity.

```
 EmployeeAdapter mAdapter;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      mAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Employee>());
      ListView employeeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.employees);
      employeeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 }
```

and when the data is modified or retrieved call this:

```
mAdapter.setEmployees(data);
```

which represents this method in the `Adapter` class itself:

```
public void setEmployees(List<Employee> data) {
    employees.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option can be nice as it encapsulates the logic on how to properly add items to the adapter. If you do this in multiple places you will not forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after updating the data as an example.

However, there is also a third option. You can add and remove items directly on the `ArrayAdapter` and by default this will call `notifyDataSetChanged()` internally.

The `ArrayAdapter` has the following methods to modify its elements and calling these methods will internally call `notifyDataSetChanged()` as long as you do not call `setNotifyOnChange(false)`.

```
addAll(Collection<? extends T> collection)
addAll(T ... items)
insert(T object, int index)
remove(T object)
clear()
```

So for the second example you really don't need the `setEmployees()` method as you can do `mAdapter.addAll(data)`.